# How to call WebAPI method from our Console application?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, console, console-application

I need to call webapi from a console application. I have written the
following code but it is not working:

```
private static async Task UploadDataFromWebApi() {
    try {
        System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8077/api/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        var resp2 =await  client.GetAsync("Report/GetReportGroup");
        resp2.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var aaa = resp2.Content;
        string result = await aaa.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }    
    catch(Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

But If I am calling the same url that is:
    `http://localhost:8077/api/Report/GetReportGroup` from the Rest client
then it is working fine.

So how can I call the web api methods from my console app?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: instead of resp2.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); check status code and content of response

Answer (score 1):

Below code works for me:-

```
Console.WriteLine("Making API Call...");
using (var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate }))
{
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8077/api/");
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("Report/GetReportGroup").Result;
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
  string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
Console.WriteLine("Result: " + result);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```